# Application doesn't update automatically on the android emulator using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having a problem when I try to run the new update code in Eclipse. For example when I try to run my app and display it in the emulator it works fine but when I change something and try to run it again it doesn't change the layout in the emulator. To view the latest update I always close my emulator and I will run again in the Eclipse.

I am new in Android Development and I hope that you can help me. That's all thanks.

Comment: yeap that's the way...close emulator and start again...I never find another way...try Genymotion.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. :)